# BIND9 nsupdate apex domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, domain-name, dns-zone, nsupdate

I've got a BIND zone like this example.com
There's a following A Record: @ --> destination IP

Now I want to update this record with, nsupdate. Can I just call update delete @ and then update add @ A new IP.

Or is this not possiboe with @ records?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no you wouldn't be able too.

However, if you're using slaves (and are able to mass-change, or less-change values), then yes, you can use NSupdate.

More information on how to do it can be found here:
https://debian-administration.org/article/591/Using_the_dynamic_DNS_editor_nsupdate

Comment: So which command do I need to update the "root domain" example.com without using @?

Answer (score 0):

from: https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/bind-users/2008-May/070326.html

> "Root domain" is confusing; I usually use the term "apex".
>
> I've never had a problem nsupdate'ing the apex of the zone. Just spell
>   the zone name out and make sure to terminate it with a dot:
>
> ```
> "update add example.com. 86400 a 1.2.3.4"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> "update add example.com. 86400 mx 10 smtp.example.com."
> ```
>
> - Kevin

I can also confirm this with my own experience today.